# Upload validation, allowing other extensions?

Tags: php

At the moment I have allowed for .jpg files to be uploaded.

How do I add jpeg, gif and png?

My current code is as follows...

```
$filename = basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);
            $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

            //Check if the file is JPEG image and it's size is less than 5Mb
$allowedExts = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
            if ( (in_array($ext, $allowedExts)) && ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") && ($_FILES["photo"]["size"] <= 5242880) ){
                //Determine the path to which we want to save this file
                $newname = str_replace( ' ', '_', trim( strip_tags( $_POST['name'] ) ) ) . _ . $formKey->generateKey() . '_' . time() . '.jpg';
```

Comment: Surely you can have at least a guess, and there is a good chance it is correct. Have a go, and we'll tell you if it it's correct.

Comment: @alex: Thanks. Uploaded an edit

Comment: Updated an edit of a further attempt.

Comment: Thanks for having a go. It was correct, except for not checking the MIME type or writing the new extension :)

Comment: @Alex: Thanks - yep only realised afterwards :) next time I'll give it a go prior to posting a question. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an array of allowed extensions, and check against it. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php.

You'd end with something like:

```
$allowedExts = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'); // Add more here
if (in_array($ext, $allowedExts))
{
    // Do something here
}
```

Also, to check the extension of a file, I suggest you to use pathinfo: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php
Some people can trick you with uploading files ending with .jpg, but that could be .php files.

[EDIT] Updated as I hate the mini-commenting:

```
   $allowedExtensions = array("image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif", "image/pjpeg", "image/jpg");
   $pathInfo = pathinfo($_FILES["photo"]["type"]);
   if (in_array($pathInfo['extension'], $allowedExtensions))
   {
       // Do stuff
   }
```

Waaaay simpler this way. This can even be simplified by using pathinfo's second parameter, but I'm assuming you'll need the other elements of the array after.

Comment: Forgot this `if ( (in_array($ext, $allowedExts)) && ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") && ($_FILES["photo"]["size"] <= 5242880) )`

Comment: Perfect and yes, much, much cleaner! Thank you Warpten

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
if(file_exists($path_image) && in_array(exif_imagetype($path_image),array(1, 2, 3, 6))){ ... }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php